# Javascript drag and drop file in container: how to prevent `dragover` from being called many times causing delay?

Tags: javascript, html

I am implementing a simple drag and drop of files in container concept. Right now, when I drag a file into the container and then drop it, the `"preventDefaults: dragover"` keeps getting called for few seconds repeatedly.

If I drag the file and instantly drop it, then it calls it a few times with a second or 2 delay. If I drag the file and then move it around above the container a few times and then drop it, then it calls it thousands of times with many seconds delay and the browser freezes too.

Here's the demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/4105uexo/

Make sure to click on console at the bottom right to see the log.

I have looked at a few other questions on SO but they all point to using `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` but I already have that in place.

I am using this sample code which seems to use exactly what I am doing but for some reason mine isn't working:

https://codepen.io/joezimjs/pen/yPWQbd

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        html {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background: black;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        x-dragdropview {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;

        }

        x-dragdropview .drag-drop {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            font-size: 50pt;
            color: white;
            display: none;
            border: 2pt dashed red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <x-dragdropview>
        <div style="display: flex; width: 100%; height: 100%; justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; font-size: 50pt; color: white;"><span>DRAG / DROP HERE</span></div>
    </x-dragdropview>
    <script>
        var dragTarget
        function preventDefaults(e) {
            console.log("preventDefaults: " + e.type);
            e.preventDefault()
            e.stopPropagation()
        }
        class XDragDropView extends HTMLElement {
            constructor() {
                super()
                this.style.display = 'block'
                this.style.position = 'relative'
                this.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div class="drag-drop"></div>`)

                Array.from(['dragenter', 'dragover', 'dragleave', 'drop']).forEach(eventName => {
                    this.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false)
                })

                Array.from(['dragenter', 'dragover']).forEach(eventName => {
                    this.addEventListener(eventName, highlight, false)
                })

                Array.from(['dragleave', 'drop']).forEach(eventName => {
                    this.addEventListener(eventName, unhighlight, false)
                })

                function highlight(e) {
                    if (e.type == "dragenter") {
                        dragTarget = e.target
                        this.querySelector('.drag-drop').style.display = 'flex'
                        console.log("highlight: " + e.target)
                    }
                }

                function unhighlight(e) {
                    if (e.target === dragTarget) {
                        this.querySelector('.drag-drop').style.display = 'none'
                        dragTarget = null
                        console.log("unhighlight: " + e.target)
                    }
                }
                this.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false)
            }
        }
        window.customElements.define('x-dragdropview', XDragDropView)

        function handleDrop(e) {
            console.log(e.dataTransfer.files[0])
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why not just remove `console.log("preventDefaults: " + e.type);` ? This seems to be the cause of the hanging, so lets at least try to just erase that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried your code in Chrome and Firefox. Both appear to work fine and does not cause any delay. The `dragover` event is supposed to fire while a file over the container ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/dragover_event)).

In the sample code you linked the `dragover` event is also fired just like yours, but it isn't printed to the console. Does that page slow down your browser also?

You could try removing your `console.log` statement completely, or change your code to not log `dragover` events.

Actually, I now realize you are talking about the JSFiddle console. It appears that the console there is not able to keep up with the amount of `console.log` calls. Either refrain from logging `dragover` events or download your code from JSFiddle and open it in your browser.

Comment: When i tried out both fiddles, they both did not slow down my browser at all, and worked just as they should. While moving the file around on your example for 10 seconds, there were about 600 console logs, which means that the handling function getts called about 60 times per second. Maybe your viewing device is just too slow to handle that amount of console logs

Comment: @Programmer Just making sure, you've opened the **integrated** console in JSFiddle? I believe that's the one causing issues for OP.

Comment: @Programmer the logs come from unnecessary repeatedly logging the **events that are going to be canceled**, thus it doesn't really matters for how many times the `preventDefaults` will be called, that is its' purpose. What it matters, is **NOT** to `console.log` anything inside that intense procedure (`preventDefaults`) that will get called hundreds of times in order to cancel the `dragover` events.

Comment: @J.W yes i opened the integrated one.

Comment: @Programmer After I comment out the console.log, the slow down no longer occurs. So it seems that's the cause of the issue. I had the console.log for debugging purposes but I guess that itself was the cause of the problem. Thanks, I will accept this answer.